# How to use operating system ability of copy and paste using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a winform application.
I have menu like Edit -> Copy and Edit -> Paste.

Instead of using     `Clipboard` class to do copying and pasting can I use Operating System's ability to Copy and Paste text, image, link, etc...

Comment: Im sure you can use some un-managed code for this.

Answer (score 1):

`Clipboard` class is just a wrapper around the System clipboard, therefore you are using the system clipboard in the background.

- [MSDN - Clipboard Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [MSDN - Clipboard.SetDataObject Method (Object, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs5ebdfz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [CodeProject - Clipboard handling with .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2207/Clipboard-handling-with-NET)

Comment: The Clipboard class is a horrifying piece of crap that requires to run in a single thread apartment though, which can be quite annoying in certain scenarios. I think my solution for this problem was creating one more thread, make it STA and use the Clipboard functionality inside.

Comment: @Michal. In Clipboard i have to set some data object. I want to utilize Operating System's Ability of copy and paste so that irespective of textbox selected value, image, table, content will be copied.

Comment: @MARKANDBhatt You want the Clipboard.SetDataObject Method, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs5ebdfz(v=vs.110).aspx